# Wordpress Authenticate never reaches echo

Tags: php

Posting for one of my teammates, we are confused as to why neither echo is reached when this code runs.  (The my website is replaced with ours of course)
Here's the code used:

```
$user = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

require_once( 'http://mywebsite/wp-includes/user.php');

$auth = wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password);

if (is_wp_error($auth)) {

echo 'not authenticated';

} else {

echo 'authenticated';

}
```

Looking for ideas/thoughts, thanks a bunch!  If more info is needed I'll ask him to look at this post later.

Comment: before that code block put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` you should see errors

Comment: is there any chance that user.php includes the function is_wp_error() ? I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't require a file as you defined. If you try to requeire a file by http:// you only get an rendered html page.

This is wrong:

```
require_once( 'http://mywebsite/wp-includes/user.php');
```

You should call it in your local path.

Like this :

```
require_once( '../wp-includes/user.php');
```